# passenger-install-apache2-module fails on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I've installed `gem install passenger` for my rails app. Now I try `passenger-install-apache2-module`.

I get errors screen:

> Installation instructions for required software
>
> - To install Apache 2 development headers:
>     Please run apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev as root.
> - To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
>     Please run apt-get install libapr1-dev as root.
> - To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
>     Please run apt-get install libaprutil1-dev as root.

When I run `sudo  apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev`, I get

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  apache2-prefork-dev :
>   Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1) but 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.1 is
>   to be installed.
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it doesn't solve anything. The error still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then retry installing apache, plus all the dev packages. You may have to uninstall apache first.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

I did that and passenger-install-apache2-module was able to pass the mentioned errors.

Comment: This helped me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the fix was to **re-enable the `precise-updates` repository** - I had disabled it in the Update Manager - and updating the system after that.

(I would have liked to only install important security updates, that's why I had disabled it in the first place.)

Comment: To whoever downvoted me: I proposed an answer that solved the identical problem for me. I'm sorry it didn't work for you, but IMO I don't deserve a downvote. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I've +1 to make it even

Comment: me too, +1ed. For justice.

Comment: FOOORRR JUSSTICCEEEE

Answer (score 0):

There is also a pre-made package for passenger in the Precise repo:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

Comment: Btw., just for the record: I discovered the same problem as Elmor after upgrading to Precise from 10.04 (iirc). apache2.2-common seems to be badly broken. apt-get fix/clean/autoremove/update/upgrade and so on did not help much.

Comment: Still didnt fix it for me. :(