# errors on installing passenger module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I can't install passenger-install-apache2-module. I'm using Apache/2.4.7(Ubuntu) and my distribution version is Ubuntu 12.04.

- To install Apache 2 development headers:
  Please install it with apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
         **Errors** -- apache2-threaded-dev : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4)
- To install Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers:
  Please install it with apt-get install libapr1-dev
- To install Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers:
  Please install it with apt-get install libaprutil1-dev

I've tryied this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792922/passenger-install-apache2-module-fails-on-ubuntu-12-04) but it didn't solve my errors.

My rvm list

```
 * ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ] (current)
```

Comment: are you installing/setting up Redmine? it souns to me like a familiar issue doing that

Comment: No, I don't know noting about Redmine. I,m following the phusion passenger guide : http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html